# Netlogo - Call go forever from another function

Tags: netlogo

I want to be able to run multiple simulation instances one after the other. What I have done, is create a "Multi-Run" button that calls a function that will call go as many times as the user asks.

The problem is that running go in a loop doesn't seem to operate the same as running go "forever" (as the button allows you to). I have stop conditions within go that allow for the simulation to stop when certain conditions are met.

How do I achieve this? OR How can I run multiple simulations one after the other successfully? Can I do this by calling Netlogo in Python?

Comment: The issue is not with go, but with stop. Stop exits the current procedure. If that's the prosecute called by the button, the button stops, too. So if something else called go, then stop exits go and the caller continues.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to use a global variable to track the `stop?` state for each run, then your `multi-run` procedure can check that to see if it's time to move on to the next run.

You didn't provide code, so here is a simple example.

```
globals [
  stop?
  run-number
  initial-value
]

to multi-run
  let run-settings [1 3 5 7 9 11]
  set run-number 0
  foreach run-settings [ setting ->
    set stop? false
    set initial-value setting
    setup
    while [not stop?] [ 
      go 
    ]
    show-results
    set run-number (run-number + 1)
  ]
end

to setup
  create-turtles initial-value
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask n-of (random initial-value) turtles [ forward 10 ]
  tick
  if (ticks > 100) [ set stop? true ]
end

to show-results
  show run-number
  show mean [xcor] of turtles
  show mean [ycor] of turtles
end
```

If you use this method I recommend adding a tick limit to `set stop? true` even if that's not your primary criteria, just in case your model hits a scenario where it's never going to stop on its own.

To make sure you are aware:  if you just want to generate results for multiple runs of a model to a CSV format but you don't really care about the UI updating throughout, you should check out [the built-in BehaviorSpace feature](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html) which is designed to do just that.